# how to access dates from the selectable property in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

FullCalendar lets you set selectable: true; meaning you can highlight multiple days on the calendar. I am trying to allow users to create an event that starts and ends on the days selected and highlighted by fullcalendar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for select callback, there you receive the start and the end of the selection.

From the [documentation - Select(callback)](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/)

> A callback that will fire after a selection is made.
>
> function( start, end, jsEvent, view )
>
> **start** is a Moment indicating the
> beginning of the selection.
>
> **end** is a Moment indicating the end of the selection. It is an
> exclusive value, so if the selection is all-day, and the last day is a
> Thursday, end will be Friday.)

example:

```
select: function(start, end, view)
        {
            window.location = "edit_event_form.cfm?&start_date="+start+"&end_date="+end+"&view="+view;
        }
```

Comment: perfect! feeling a little silly for not realizing this was the solution I was looking for. much thanks.